# How to make your own custom based tile app - not pined to startscreen in windows phone 8

Tags: windows, layout, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Hey I am looking to make a windows 8 phone app that has a tile look and feel. I am not interested in making it pined to the start screen. I want an app that has it's own functionality in the tiles. Does anyone know how to make that layout - could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit dll supports a control named hubtile.

**"The latest version of Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit provides Windows Phone HubTile control. This control can make your application stylish by adding animated tiles in it. HubTile can consist of an image, title, message or a notification. In this example we will represent HubTile in two different ways, Static HubTile and Dynamic HubTile".**

Best links

[One](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/HubTile_in_Windows_Phone)

[Two](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-hubtile-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api)

Comment: following both links, I keep getting an error:
The name "HubTile" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit". I added the windows phone controls via Library Packet Manager(Nuget), still gives errors

Comment: Okay manually made a project and took some of the xaml code and now it runs without errors. What project type would you recommend for this?

Comment: Do you know why my images on hubtiles are not displaying when emulating? when editing they are there

Comment: that happens with me as well, But Sorry, I am short of answers on this.

Comment: I found the solution. open project in blend -> right click hubtile -> edit a copy -> on the left you will see the posibility to set an image. now it will apply the style to the specific hubtile